# Decoding escaped unicode in Python 3 from a non-ascii string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, escaping, decode

I have been searching for hours now to find a way to fully reverse the result of a str.encode-call like this:

```
"testäch基er".encode("cp1252", "backslashreplace")
```

The result is

```
b'test\xe4ch\\u57faer'
```

now i want to convert it back with

```
b'test\xe4ch\\u57faer'.decode("cp1252")
```

and I get

```
'testäch\\u57faer'
```

So how do I get my 基 back? I'm getting nearly there by using decode("unicode-escape") instead (it would work for this example), but that assumes bytes encoded with iso8859-1 not cp1252, so any characters between 80 and 9F would be wrong.

Comment: It would be useful to give some context. What are you doing with those bytes? Displaying them? Or storing them in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was still very new to Python when I asked this question. Now I understand that these fallback mechanisms are just meant for handling unexpected errors, not something to save and restore data. If you really need a simple and reliable way to encode single unicode characters in ASCII, have a look at the `quote` and `unquote` functions from the `urllib.parse` module.

Answer (score 5):

Well...

```
>>> b'test\xe4ch\\u57faer'.decode('unicode-escape')
'testäch基er'
```

**But** `backslashreplace`->`unicode-escape` is *not* a consistent round trip. If you have backslashes in the original string, they won't get encoded by `backslashreplace` but they will get decoded by `unicode-escape`, and replaced with unexpected characters.

```
>>> '☃ \\u2603'.encode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape')
'☃ ☃'
```

There is no way to reliably reverse the encoding of string that has been encoded with an `errors` fallback such as `backslashreplace`. That's why it's a fallback, if you could consistently encode and decode to it, it would have been a real `encoding`.

Comment: I'm now using the `quote` and `unquote` functions from the `urllib.parse` module to achieve a safe and standards-compliant escaping of unicode characters. See accepted answer.