# How to convert ASCII encoded UTF8 string back to UTF8?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, decode, encode, data-conversion

The short question: "Is **str.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')** reversable"?

In the following code snippet, is it possible to convert `y` back to `x`?

```
x = "\u042d\u0442\u043e"
len(x)
3
y = x.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
y
b'\\u042d\\u0442\\u043e'
len(y)
18
```

It is not an idle question. I have raw data coming in this format and I need to convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: There is no way to reliably reverse the encoding of string that has been encoded with an errors fallback such as `backslashreplace`. See the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327170/decoding-escaped-unicode-in-python-3-from-a-non-ascii-string

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It works well in my specific case.